# Adding errors in .fsx files into the Visual Studio error list

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, f#

I have an F# solution in Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise) with several projects in which control various pieces of hardware.  In each project there are `.fsx` script files which demonstrate how the API is used to do basic tasks on the hardware.  If I make changes to the API and rebuild, then I correctly get the Error List populated with all the errors from the compiled `.fs` files, but since the `.fsx` aren't required to make the `.dll`s, then I don't get errors from them when I change the underlying API.

If I open each `.fsx` file individually in the editor, then I get the Error List populated for as long as the file is open, but I'd like to have them block the build and all appear, rather than having to go through each in turn, which takes quite a while.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would add a custom build step for verifying the `fsx` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion from Fyodor would certainly work - but I guess building a custom step for the build system might not be the easiest thing to do!

A simple alternative would be to add a separate F# project that contains the `fsx` files and compiles them - then you can just ignore the result of the building the project.

When you add `fsx` file to project, it is not compiled as part of the project build, but you can change that by choosing `Compile` as an "Action" in the properties window in Visual Studio. Alternatively, you can just edit the `fsproj` file:

```
<Compile Include="some.fsx" />
```

When editing the file by hand, you can also make it point into another folder:

```
<Compile Include="..\OtherProject\some.fsx" />
```